# Maintaining Row Sequence across multiple tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have triggers on multiple tables that capture updates to a table (Capture Table). Once that insert is complete the trigger completes and control returns to the calling application. It's expected that this capture table will receive about 1.75 million records per day.

I then have a Windows service that runs and takes the data from the Capture Table, adds some context by referencing other tables in our database, then inserts records into a notification table that is used by another process.
Our Capture Table has an `IDENTITY` column and a `DATETIME` to help with sequencing. For the `DATETIME`, we set a variable to `GETDATE()` and use the variable so that all records in the same transaction will have the exact same `DATETIME`.

I am looking at making the process more robust. At this point the Windows service calls a stored procedure and processes one transaction at a time in sequence. This could become a bottleneck. We may need to process multiple transactions at the same time.

How can I guarantee the sequence is the same between the Capture Table and the notification table? It’s critical that the records stay in the same order. Thanks for your input!

[image: Flow diagram]

Comment: Something is missing in the explanation here. Not quite sure what the problem is. It sounds like you have a datetime column that could be used for ordering?

Comment: Sean - if a 50,000 row transaction begins and a second transaction with only has 1 row is performed, wouldn't the 1 row land in the table before the 50,000 have finished updating?  In this case the datetimes would be out of sequence?